# problem in the output of query - php+json

Tags: php, mysql, json

```
function tableOne() {

        $query = mysql_query("SELECT valor FROM grafico") or die(mysql_error());
        $i = 0;
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
            $arr[] = array($row[valor]);
            ++$i;
        }
        echo json_encode($arr);
    }
}
```

the output will be

`[["15573"],["31978"],["11227"],["5752"],["20817"],["32182"]]`

i need something like:

```
["15573","31978","11227","5752","20817","32182","10935"]
```

i tried some changes in the code but the output is not what i want.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are placing sub-arrays in each element of your array.  You should replace

```
$arr[] = array($row[valor]);
```

with

```
$arr[] = $row[valor];
```

The `[]` in `$arr[]` already adds each entry as an element of the array.

Comment: Also, please quote your array indices (`'valor'`).

Comment: it is possible an output without quotes [15573,1978, 200]?

Comment: Try casting the values to an int: `(int)$row[valor];`

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT valor FROM grafico") or die(mysql_error());

$arr = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $arr[] = $row['valor'];  // get rid of the array() wrapper
}

echo json_encode($arr);
```